# Is OLE automation a good choice to automate IE via C++?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, automation, ole

I am new to machine-oriented programming and..

I want to open a website in IE - download the whole content of that site - and save it to a specified temporary file. What is the best way to do this with pure C++? Any suggestions and / or examples? I stumbled over OLE automation. Would that be a good choice?

Sencerely, Konstanze

Comment: To run away, hide in a corner and cry? ;)

Comment: IE is not the best tool for this - have you looked at wget?

Comment: I know that there are plenty other and better solutions to download the content of a website but I want to use IE deliberately.

Comment: Why are you rejecting better solutions?

Comment: I am doing some security related research.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 'pure' C++ then automation's your best shot.

You could also do this in C++/CLI.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752044(v=vs.85).aspx

Scroll to the bottom for C++ samples.

Also, familiarize yourself with the basic concepts of COM before you move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off:

1. opening a HTTP connection to the page you want to download;
2. open a write handle to the temporary file;
3. read the connection data into a temporary buffer;
4. write the content of the buffer to the file handle from (2);
5. repeat steps (3) and (4) in a loop until there is no more data;
6. close the file and http connection handles.

You should be able to google for the APIs to use (IIRC, something like HttpOpen on windows).

Comment: Please take a look at my comment above (: